# Find the equation of the tangent line at an intersection

Tags: calculus, tangent-line

Find the equation of the tangent line at $y^2=6x-3$ that is perpendicular to the line $x+3y=7$

My answer : $y=(2\sqrt{30}-9)+3(x-34+6\sqrt{30})$

Graphing the line seems close enough but after more than 10 pages of paper I don't really know what to do anymore. send help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Line has slope $-(1/3)$, recall $-(1/3)m=-1$ gives $m$ , the perpendicular slope.

Hence: $m=3;$

Differentiate $y^2=6x -3$.

$2y\dfrac{dy}{dx} =6;$

Setting $\dfrac{dy}{dx} =3$:

$2y(3)= 6;$ $ y=1.$

$6x-3=1$; $6x=4$; $x= 2/3$.

Tangent line:

$y-1= 3(x-2/3).$

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

The equation of any straight line perpendicular to $x+3y=7$ is $$3x-y=k$$

Now let us find the intersection of this line with $y^2=6x-3$

$$y^2=2(y+k)-3\iff y^2-2y+3-2k=0\ \  \ \ (1)$$ which is a Quadratic Equation $y$ whose roots represent the ordinates of intersection.

For tangency, both roots must coincide.

So, the discriminant of $(1)$ must be $0$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: So I should use $3x-y+k = y^2-2y+3-2k$ to find the intersection or I substitute k?

Comment: @RichardMarin, We need to eliminate one of the variables, right?

Comment: I got $y=\sqrt{2k-2}+1$. I think that I should assume that k=constant then just substitute this to the point slope form. Is this correct?